# XGrid or Data Grid: How to restrict filter operators in the tool bar?

Tags: material-ui

I have setup an Material-UI's XGrid on a page and the API backing it only supports 'equals' as the filter operator. How can I hide other operators in the toolbar?

[Screenshot of the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gFZv.png)

Answer (score 9):

The solution involves

- accessing the built-in "string type" filters using `getGridStringOperators` provided by the grid's api
- with a ref to those filters, go ahead and filter them for what your api supports
- finally, set the column prop with the result.

Optionally, you might consider creating a custom prop to display your search field in the header.

Here is what the code might look like:

```js
import {
  XGrid as DataGrid,
  getGridStringOperators,
} from '@material-ui/x-grid';

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Column-related configuration
//
const filterOperators = getGridStringOperators().filter(({ value }) =>
  ['equals' /* add more over time */ ].includes(value),
);

const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', hide: true },
  {
    field: 'myEqualOnlyField',
    className: ['myEqualOnlyField'], // not required
    sortable: true, // not required
    filterOperators, // <<< required for what you want
    flex: 1, // not required
    // renderHeader: () => <SearchField />, <<< perhaps useful for a single, equal only option search  
  },
  {
    ...other fields/columns
  },
];
```

The docs don't seem to provide an explicit example for what you want to accomplish. Nonetheless, here is the link to the [related documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/#data-grid-filtering).

Finally, to round-out the answer, in the event you want to add your own filter, i.e., one that is not part of the built-in filters, [here is a link](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/#create-a-custom-operator).